# Spring Controller application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have been viewing several Spring MVC Controller examples, and the ones I've found show one controller handling multiple views.  Which this approach seems fine, but which I could see becoming clumsy in a large web-sites.

Given something like:

```
Accounts
    /AcctsRec
    /AcctsPay
```

I can see where one Account controller would work for that setup.

Now Add:

```
Security
    /Login
    /Rights
```

Again I can see one Security Controller.

But now add in something like.  If Security/Rights allows access to Accounts/AcctsPay.  Would that be a third controller?  Or would Security/Rights pass an object to Accounts/AcctsPay? Or Accounts Controller?

How would that work?

A pseudo code example, a pointer to a web-site example, or anything helpful would be appreciated.
Only please don't direct me to the Spring's documentation. I've read that a couple to times and just can't seem to gleam much from it.

Comment: Are you talking about the logic that each controller encapsulates? Or are you talking about the view/data they return?

Answer (score 0):

*But now add in something like. If Security/Rights allows access to Accounts/AcctsPay. Would that be a third controller? Or would Security/Rights pass an object to Accounts/AcctsPay? Or Accounts Controller*

I think there is some confusion as to what is going on because the above doesn't make any sense. The paths you have above are URLs. Each one typically maps an HTTP request to a `@Controller` handler method that produces an HTTP response.

Perhaps `/Accounts/AcctsPay` is not accessible without authentication and authorization. And maybe `/Security/Login` authenticates you and `/Security/Rights` gives you some permissions. In this scenario, you would need to send a request to `/Security/Login` to get authenticated, then another request to `/Security/Rights` to get some permissions, and finally a request to `/Accounts/AcctsPay` to perform some action.

A `@Controller` method is meant for handling requests. Handling it by responding with a 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden is still a valid response.

Comment: Ok, I probably muddied the waters by the Security example.  The point I was trying to understand is path 1 (/Accounts..) could be one controller handling all sub paths below Accounts.  Path 2 (/foo, /foo/bar,..) could be another controller handling foo and related sub tasks.  But traveling from /foo/bar view to say /Accounts/AcctsPay view with some data from the /foo/bar view. Would that be another controller mapping to /Accounts/AcctsPay with the data object?

Comment: You're at `/foo/bar`, you the send a request to `/Accounts/AcctsPay`. I don't see what the problem is. That same controller handler method would handle it. I still don't see what's troubling you.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I guess it's transferring the data collected in say /foo/bar to /Accounts/AcctsPay.     Being able to display /Accounts/AcctsPay without a data object or with the data object.

Comment: Depending on the object you're trying to transfer, there are a number of methods available, none of which matter which Controller class is doing it. You can use `Model` attributes, `HttpServletRequest` attributes, `HttpSession` attributes, hidden `<input>` fields, etc.